# Does anyone know what set these parts belong to? Lots of dark red, with tans and greys

Tags: set-identification

I cannot identify these parts.  Dark gray and dark red parts with one figure.[image: Lots of dark red, with tans and greys]

Comment: That round piece near the minifig head would probably give it away if you flip it over, as those patterns tend to be unique (or very nearly so).

Answer (score 10):

Based on [48336](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=48336&colorID=115&in=A) Pearl Gold Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle on Side - Closed Ends and [47759](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47759&colorID=59&in=A) Dark Red Wedge 2 x 4 Triple

[76104-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76104-1) The Hulkbuster Smash-Up

[image: 76104-1]